# Funny behavior when scrolling to section of page using smooth scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a home page that when a link it clicked, it opens another page and then scrolls to the appropriate section using the div's ID. When the page loads, it seems to already be on the correct div, but then it flashes and goes to the top of the page and then scrolls down to the correct section.

Here is my JS:

```
if (window.location.hash !== null && window.location.hash !== '') 
   $('body').animate({
      scrollTop: $(window.location.hash).offset().top - 90,
   }, 1500);
```

Here is a link to the site:

http://staging.globaltc.org

If you see the Pray. Give. Go. section under the map, those are the links that I am concerned with.

Comment: could you please create a jsfiddle so that the issue can be understood well

Comment: I am not sure what else you can get from a fiddle because you cannot perform what I am trying to do with a fiddle, but here you go: http://codepen.io/dcain19/pen/pJxwbQ

Comment: Its fine in my browser. I am with Linux Mint, Fire Fox v39.0